# Adding BigDecimal Value to editText - Android, Java

Tags: java, android, xml

I have some edit text fields that i want to populate with a BigDecimal (or whatever data type that im allowed to populate them with ?) as follows:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/enterTenYear"
    style="@style/inputs"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/customPaymentText"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/interestRateText"
    android:layout_marginBottom="57dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number|numberDecimal" >
</EditText>
```

And i want to set this edit text field with a value... (BigDecimal):

```
enterTenYear.setText(amountWithInterest.divide(tenYear));
```

What should I change `enterTenYear.` ? here ? `(amountWithInterest.divide(tenYear));`
to make this work ?

Do i need to cast the BigDecimals or what?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to turn it into some sort of character sequence, like a string.  Calling .toString() is probably enough.

Comment: enterTenYear.setText((CharSequence) amountWithInterest.divide(tenYear));                 Like that ?